# How to set the items in random position in the Gridview?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-adapter, android-gridview

I am working on one Launcher Application, and i have one doubt i want to clarify.
How to set the items in random position in the `GridView`, when the user will drag one app and drop it into the desktop at the time it will set automatically in the any of the position.

I have already completed most the parts only I am not able to set the position, it's always setting the adapter in the first position.

**App List Screen**

[image]

**App List Screen Code**

```
AppDetailsAdapter adapter = new AppDetailsAdapter(list, longListener);
appList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 4));
appList.setAdapter(adapter);

/*Inside AppDetailsAdapter*/

holder.appIconView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    Log.d("AppsDrag", "onLongClick..." + v.getTag().toString());
    mListener.onItemLongClick(position, holder.appIconView);
    return true;
  }
});

holder.appIconView.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
      Log.d("AppsDrag", "onDrag..." + event.getAction());
      mListener.onItemDragListener(v, event);
      return true;
    }
});

public OnAppItemClickListener longListener = new OnAppItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemLongClick(int position, View v) {
       ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
       View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
       v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
       v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemDragListener(View v, DragEvent event) {
         mAppCardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                Log.d(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");
            break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                Log.d(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
            break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                Log.d(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
            break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                Log.d(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION ");
            break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                Log.d(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
            break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DROP event");
                DesktopApps desktopApps = new DesktopApps();
                desktopApps.setName(apps.get(mPosition).getName());
                desktopApps.setLabel(apps.get(mPosition).getLabel());
                desktopApps.setIcon(apps.get(mPosition).getIcon());
                desktopAppses.add(desktopApps);

                DesktopAppDetailsAdapter mDesktopAdapter = new 
 DesktopAppDetailsAdapter(desktopAppses, desktopListener);
                desktopList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 5));
                desktopList.setAdapter(mDesktopAdapter);
             break;
            default:
              break;
    }
  }
};
```

**Desktop List Screen**

[image]

You can check in the below image, the item is set to first position but in the above image i have dropped in some other position.

[image]

Desktop List Screen Code

```
public class DesktopApps {
   public CharSequence label;
   public CharSequence name;
   public Drawable icon;

   public CharSequence getLabel() {
       return label;
   }

   public void setLabel(CharSequence label) {
       this.label = label;
   }

   public CharSequence getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(CharSequence name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public Drawable getIcon() {
       return icon;
   }

   public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
       this.icon = icon;
   }
}

public class DesktopAppDetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DesktopAppDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

   private ArrayList<DesktopApps> mAppList;
   private MainActivity.OnDesktopAppItemClickListener mListener;

   public DesktopAppDetailsAdapter(ArrayList<DesktopApps> appList, MainActivity.OnDesktopAppItemClickListener listener) {
        this.mAppList = appList;
        this.mListener = listener;
   }

   @Override
   public DesktopAppDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.adapter_desktop_app_list, parent, false);
       return new ViewHolder(itemView);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(DesktopAppDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
      holder.appIconView.setImageDrawable(mAppList.get(position).getIcon());
      holder.appNameView.setText(mAppList.get(position).getLabel());

      holder.appIconView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             mListener.onItemClick(position);
         }
      });
      holder.appIconView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            mListener.onItemLongClick(position);
            return true;
        }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
      return mAppList.size();
  }

  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     private ImageView appIconView;
     private TextView appNameView;

     public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
         super(itemView);
         appIconView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
         appNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
     }
  }
}
```

Please kindly go through my above post and let me know.

Thanks